# javascript to change text contents in JS file

Tags: javascript, java

[image]i have an .js file in which Text contents have to replaced with the text content in excel

for example

```
var gCategory_CircuitDiagram = "Circuit Diagram";
var gCategory_HarnessLayout = "Harness Layout";
var gCategory_PowerSource_Grounding_SneakPath1 = "Power Source";
var gCategory_PowerSource_Grounding_SneakPath2 = "Power Source / Grounding / Sneak Path";
var gCategory_Connector = "Connector";
var gCategory_Junction = "Connection information";
```

in this textcontents("Circuit Diagram") inside the double quotes i have to replace with contents in excel can anybody tell me how to get JS file and xml data as input replace all the  text contents , i will be very thankful to you if you help me in this case.

with regards,
karthik

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. If it was I assume it is, I don't think you can use JS in Excel.

Comment: i will explain clearly sir,

Comment: i have to find "Circuit Diagram"; and replace with text content in xml file and next content "Harness Layout"; i have to find out in excel and i have to replace. like this many js files i hve to replace this text contents manually i am editing this text contents

Comment: If you are trying to do it on server side, check answer below. If you are trying to do it in client browser, think you should get binary data of your excel doc, and work with it. Absolutely sure that you will have a headache and nothing more, but you can try to search for some libs. How to get data - 1. using xmlhttprequest; 2. Using `<input type="file"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what process you're trying to develop here exactly.

From what I get you could write a script using nodeJS and 2 module, xlsx and xml2js.

The xlsx module would allow you to read your excel file  and get a Object from it.

You can then edit this object with your list of changes ('circuit diagram', etc.).

When it's done you can generate an xml file with the xml2js module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js